# How to redirect old directory to new one on IIS

Tags: iis, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect an old directory to the new one (301 redirection). In my case i want this :

- http://www.mydomain.com/xxxx/ redirect to http://www.mydomain.com/yyyy/
- http://www.mydomain.com/xxxx/1-my-product-name redirect to http://www.mydomain.com/yyyy/1-my-product-name
- http://www.mydomain.com/xxxx/c/my-category-name redirect to http://www.mydomain.com/yyyy/c/my-category-name
- etc...

To do this, I use the URL Rewriting module on IIS to do this. This is my rule in my web.config :

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="xxxx" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="yyyy{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
```

It works fine with http://www.mydomain.com/xxxx/1-my-product-name and http://www.mydomain.com/xxxx/c/my-category-name but when i go to http://www.mydomain.com/xxxx/ it's redirect to http://www.mydomain.com/yyyy**//** with two slahes. Anyone know how to avoid this ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found, this is the rule that i used :

```
<rule name="tpepme" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="xxxx(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="yyyy{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
```